# Why the polygon does not appear

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom map and a map renderer. Inside the renderer, I have this method in Android folder:

```
public void AddMapPolygon(double[][] polygon, MapResource mapResource)
{
    PolygonOptions options = new PolygonOptions();
    var points = new LatLng[polygon.Length];

    int index = 0;
    foreach (double[] loc in polygon)
    {
        points[index] = new LatLng(loc[0], loc[1]);
        index++;
    }
    options.Add(points);
    options.InvokeFillColor(Color.Argb(128, 255, 0, 0));
    options.InvokeStrokeColor(Color.Argb(200, 0, 0, 0));
    options.InvokeStrokeWidth(4f);
    NativeMap.AddPolygon(options);
}
```

The method is called, but the polygon is not visible on the map.
What I did wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the polygon point positions are not within the visible area?  Could you have lat/long swapped, so they are somewhere else on earth?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The lat/lng are correct. The issue is that I didn't invoke the method call in Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread().

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the polygon didn't appear was that I didn't enclose it in Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(). I believe UI related changes should be invoked in Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread().